QStackedWidget only shows the contents of the first page
In my example, I only see the first label - that's on page 1 of the stacked widget. I see no "caption" for the stacked widget's page(s), either.
class QTest : public QDialog {
public:
    QTest(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent) {
        setWindowTitle("Stacked Widget Example");

        QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        QStackedWidget* stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget(this);
        const int numPages = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPages; ++i) {
            auto* optionsPage = new QWidget(this);
            auto* formLayout = new QFormLayout(optionsPage);

            optionsPage->setWindowTitle(QString("Page %1").arg(i + 1));

            formLayout->addRow(new QLabel(QString("Label %1").arg(i + 1)), new QLineEdit(this));

            stackedWidget->addWidget(optionsPage);
        }

        mainLayout->addWidget(stackedWidget);
        setLayout(mainLayout); // Ensure layout is set to the dialog
    }
};

void foo() {
    auto* pp = new QTest(this);
    pp->exec();
}


Here's a screenshot. I'm using Qt 5 and Windows 10.

Update:
I was corrected, that my understanding of QStackedWidget was wrong. I was hoping to get something like this:


What "caption"? What you see is exactly what's expected: QStackedWidget shows only one page at a time (the current one); switching to others is done programmatically or through signals. Maybe you were actually looking for QTabWidget?

That's what QStackedWidget does.  If you want to change the page shown you need to call QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex.  Although I guess what you're actually looking for might be QTabWidget?

Thank you. I was hoping QStackedWidget was more. I updated my question, so maybe there is a Qt widget that does what I want it to do?

In UI terminology, "stacking" is always about elements placed with different "z-order", potentially overlapping themselves. Besides, the QStackedWidget docs are clear from the very first line: "The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time". Also note that what you're showing in the image (taken from Qt Designer) is actually a QTreeWidget with a custom delegate. It differentiates from your solution as it doesn't actually use widgets, but that can be achieved too (with setItemWidget()).

This question is similar to: How to make an expandable/collapsable section widget in Qt. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I managed to do what I wanted. It might be called an accordeon. Here's how I did it:
SettingsDialog::SettingsDialog(QWidget* parent, QString title, const std::vector<QString>& items):QDialog(parent) {
    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    // Create a container widget to hold the sections
    QWidget* containerWidget = new QWidget(this);
    QVBoxLayout* containerLayout = new QVBoxLayout(containerWidget);
    containerWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);

    QFormLayout* formLayout = nullptr;

    for(auto& it : m_items) {
        if(it[0] == "*") { // new group
            // header button to enable/disable this group
            QPushButton* toggleButton = new QPushButton(it, this);
            containerLayout->addWidget(toggleButton);

            QWidget* contentWidget = new QWidget(this);
            formLayout = new QFormLayout(contentWidget);

            contentWidget->setLayout(formLayout);
            contentWidget->setVisible(true);

            connect(toggleButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [contentWidget]() {
                contentWidget->setVisible(!contentWidget->isVisible());
            });

            // Set no margins or spacing for the containerLayout
            containerLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            containerLayout->setSpacing(0);

            // Add stacked widget to the main layout
            containerLayout->addWidget(contentWidget);

            it.m_pWidget = contentWidget;

            continue;
        }
        auto* pWidget = new QLineEdit(this);
        formLayout->addRow(new QLabel(it.m_displayName), pWidget);
    }

    // Create a scroll area and set the container widget as its widget
    QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
    scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
    scrollArea->setWidget(containerWidget);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    mainLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);

    // Add OK and Cancel buttons
    // Create buttons
    QPushButton* okButton = new QPushButton("OK", this);
    QPushButton* cancelButton = new QPushButton("Cancel", this);

    // Button layout
    QHBoxLayout* buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    buttonLayout->addStretch();
    buttonLayout->addWidget(okButton);
    buttonLayout->addWidget(cancelButton);
    mainLayout->addLayout(buttonLayout);

    // Connect buttons
    connect(okButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [&]() {onOK();});
    connect(cancelButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &QDialog::reject);

    setMinimumSize(320, 200); // don't like to see a horizontal scrollbar
}


With some suggar added, this might look like:


It's not a real "accordion" (with an "i"), as that normally exclusively toggles the item visibility, meaning that it shows the contents of only one item at a time (or possibly none), and Qt has that: QToolBox. Since it's clear you're also using Designer, I strongly suggest to familiarize with all widgets in the "Widget Box" in order to know their names and understand how they work. Almost all Qt widgets are there, and you must be aware of them: if you tried the "Stacked Widget" in Designer to begin with, you'd found out that it's not what you wanted.
